# Checking wether wifi Roaming Scans is enabled or not under Developer options

Tags: android, settings, android-wifi

I want to redirect the user to enable Allow Wifi Roaming Scans option under Developer Options if Allow Wifi Roaming Scans is not enabled. For that I have  checked whether developer options is enabled or nor using the below code.
Code

```
int devOptions = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);
```

This is working.It will return 1 if developer option is enabled or not 0. Now I have to check Allow wifi Roaming scans. I am not able to find the default name for that.
Please help me to do this.